# Cross Validation for Different Metrics

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, cross-validation

When I am doing cross validation using Python's Sklearn and take the score of different metrics (accuracy, precision, etc.) like this:

```
result_accuracy = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, scoring='accuracy', cv=10)
result_precision = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, scoring='precision', cv=10)
result_recall = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, scoring='recall', cv=10)
result_f1 = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, scoring='f1', cv=10)
```

Did every execution of `cross_val_score()` function for different metrics made the same 10 folds of the training data or not? If not, do I need to make the general 10-folds first using KFold, like this:

```
seed = 7
kf = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)

result_accuracy = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, scoring='accuracy', cv=kf)
result_precision = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, scoring='precision', cv=kf)
result_recall = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, scoring='recall', cv=kf)
result_f1 = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, scoring='f1', cv=kf)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use random_state param in cross_val_score to set the same splitting each time.

```
result_accuracy = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, scoring='accuracy', cv=10, random_state=42)
```